# Redirect to new domain from an existing domain (Apache / haproxy)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, haproxy

DESCRIPTION: 
We have two apache servers and one is behind haproxy. Our NEW server is behind the haproxy box, the OLD one is on a different network. I am going to create an apache rewrite rule to point this oldsite.com/some/thing to the new haproxy box (as seen below). This will redirect to newsite/some/other thing.

QUESTION:
Is it possible to make this transparent to the user? I would like the user to only see oldsite.com/some/thing and not newsite/some/other/thing ? Is this achieveable with haproxy?  I know a little about haproxy but not a lot. Thanks in advance for your time. much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In other words, point oldsite.com to newsite.com but the user only sees oldsite.com

Comment: This is not the job function of haproxy per say. You can do that with your current apache setup. Just do a proxypass or rewrite with P flag to your new VIP/Hostname and it should be transparent.

Comment: ...or install haproxy on the old server, to forward requests to the new server... but you can't do anything properly called a "redirect" without rewriting the address bar.

Comment: Thank you guys, just needed a little direction which you have provided to me nicely.. Thanks again, I posted one solution below.. a rough draft of sorts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the tip from @Panama Jack, I created a basic test which I think will work for me.  This is just the rough config and requires protections and so forth to get working fully. This is apache 2.4 (amazon AMI). As you see above, I am wanting to make the second server transparent to the user.

This example (quick and dirty) setup does the following:

- login.HOST.info = login.DESTINATION.info
- (user never sees the login.DESTINATION.info url that does the page actually exists on)

Server Handling Request:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName login.HOST.info
    ServerAlias www.login.HOST.info
    ErrorLog logs/login-error_log
    CustomLog logs/login-access_log common
    RewriteEngine On
    RequestHeader add X-SSL off
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://login.DESTINATION.info/$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Final Server Handling the Request:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName login.DESTINATION.info
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/deal/site/locator/whatever/

    RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarder-For    # allows the host to remain
    RemoteIPInternalProxy XXXX.0.0.0/8   # ip of other machine
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

See my first answer, but another way to do it is with one vhost and the use of the proxy:

## ha proxy

```
 acl loc_req url_beg -i /uri/locator/location
```

(add lines to block to older server with !loc_req etc.)

## vhost on new system

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@localhost
   ServerName login.HOST.info 
   ... ....
   Alias /uri/locator/location /www/actual/path/to/new/location
   ... .....
```